# Can Drawmij's Instant Summons retrieve a lost Leomund's Secret Chest?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Suppose that I cast *leomund's secret chest* and then bind the chest itself with *drawmij's instant summons*. I'll then send it into the Ethereal Plane, and while it's hidden, I'll end the spell effect.

*Leomund's secret chest* says that this will cause the chest to be irretrievably lost.

Finally, the question is, if I crush the sapphire after all of this, will I be able to get the chest back? *Drawmij's instant summons* says the item appears in my hand regardless of physical or planar distances.

Answer (score 7):

### No, you cannot use this spell to retrieve the chest.

Drawmij's Instant Summons states:
"You touch an object weighing 10 pounds or less"

Leomund's Secret Chest lists as a material component:
"an exquisite chest, 3 feet by 2 feet by 2 feet, constructed from rare materials worth at least 5,000 gp"

A chest weighs 25 lbs. Since Leomund's Secret Chest uses a chest as a component, rather than creates a chest, we have to use the standard info for a chest.

Since it exceeds 10 lbs, it cannot be summoned.

Comment: Good catch! I didnt notice the weights on that. But let's say you had a chest that *did* fit the weight requirements... What then?

Comment: I can very conceivably picture a chest made of 'rare materials' within the weight limit. This seems semantics rather than rules.

Comment: @Cleric It isnt clear, but I would say that since Drawmij's is 2 levels higher than Leomund's, it could retrieve the chest.

Comment: @SeriousBri Yes, there could be a chest below the weight limit, but Leomund's doesnt say anything about the chest being lighter, so it would be up to the DM. Further, what about contents? Either only the chest would travel without contents, or everything together would have to weigh less than 10 lbs.